# Javascript hover/click trouble

Tags: javascript

I have an accordian style menu which works fine on **hover** state but I'd like to change to to **click** instead...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav > li').hover(
        function() {
            if ($('> span',this).attr('class') != 'active') {
                $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
                $('span',this).next().slideToggle();
                $('#nav li span').removeClass('active');
                $('> span',this).addClass('active');
            }
        },
        function() {
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But simply replacing **hover** with **click** doesn't work, any advise much appreciated I'm a designer so my JS is pretty poor :)

Comment: of course, because hover takes 2 functions an 'on' hover and 'off' hover call back, changing it to click wont work, you'll need to put the code form the 'off' call back in a `else` part of your `if` statement

Comment: you might also use the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML, as it's impossible to tell what elements are what just from your script. Preferably as a JS Fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dukeofazard69/scgwugjz/3/

Comment: Please see JSFiddle stuff above, thanks guys for your help thus far

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav > li').click(function () {
            if ($('> span', this).attr('class') != 'active') {
                $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
                $('span', this).next().slideToggle();
                $('#nav li span').removeClass('active');
                $('> span', this).addClass('active');
            }
        }).mouseout(function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).parents().find('#' + $(this).attr('id')).length) return;
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            $('#nav li span').removeClass('active');
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<li id="t1"><span>Nav item click me 1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="t2"><span>Nav item click me 2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: Legend, it works.... Thanks John! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/dukeofazard69/scgwugjz/6/

AH, actually somethings a little sticky. Click 'Nav item click me 1' (on link above), roll off it then try to click it again, doesn't wanna play ball. Any ideas?

Comment: @keirananderson, in mouseout, we need to replace #nav li a to #nav li span. Answer updated

Comment: Ah as soon as I hover off the main nav item it cloes, so you can't get to the sub links

Comment: @keirananderson, Answer updated. li must have some id.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover(fucntion() {}, function()); // .hover() accept two function`
`.click(function() {});  // only accept one`

try

```
$('selector').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // do something if this has class active 
    } 
    else {
        // do something if not. 
    } 

} );
```